# Sorting attribute options

Tags: attributes, attribute-options

I am adding new options to some existing attributes using the method below.

```
$option['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getId();
$option['value'][$value][0] = $value;
Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->addAttributeOption($option);
```

This is working fine but how can I insert a position/sort value for the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is function addAttributeOption($option) in `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php`

```
    public function addAttributeOption($option)
    {
    $optionTable        = $this->getTable('eav/attribute_option');
    $optionValueTable   = $this->getTable('eav/attribute_option_value');

    if (isset($option['value'])) {
        foreach ($option['value'] as $optionId => $values) {
            $intOptionId = (int) $optionId;
            if (!empty($option['delete'][$optionId])) {
                if ($intOptionId) {
                    $condition = array('option_id =?' => $intOptionId);
                    $this->_conn->delete($optionTable, $condition);
                }
                continue;
            }

            if (!$intOptionId) {
                $data = array(
                    'attribute_id'  => $option['attribute_id'],
                    'sort_order'    => isset($option['order'][$optionId]) ? $option['order'][$optionId] : 0,
                );
                $this->_conn->insert($optionTable, $data);
                $intOptionId = $this->_conn->lastInsertId($optionTable);
            } else {
                $data = array(
                    'sort_order'    => isset($option['order'][$optionId]) ? $option['order'][$optionId] : 0,
                );
                $this->_conn->update($optionTable, $data, array('option_id=?' => $intOptionId));
            }

            // Default value
            if (!isset($values[0])) {
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('eav')->__('Default option value is not defined'));
            }
            $condition = array('option_id =?' => $intOptionId);
            $this->_conn->delete($optionValueTable, $condition);
            foreach ($values as $storeId => $value) {
                $data = array(
                    'option_id' => $intOptionId,
                    'store_id'  => $storeId,
                    'value'     => $value,
                );
                $this->_conn->insert($optionValueTable, $data);
            }
        }
    } else if (isset($option['values'])) {
        foreach ($option['values'] as $sortOrder => $label) {
            // add option
            $data = array(
                'attribute_id' => $option['attribute_id'],
                'sort_order'   => $sortOrder,
            );
            $this->_conn->insert($optionTable, $data);
            $intOptionId = $this->_conn->lastInsertId($optionTable);

            $data = array(
                'option_id' => $intOptionId,
                'store_id'  => 0,
                'value'     => $label,
            );
            $this->_conn->insert($optionValueTable, $data);
        }
    }
}
```

You can using array have index 'sort_order' to sort attribute. If it not setup, it have value as 0.